# How to use regex to check if URL contains upper case character in java

Tags: java

Im trying to check if URL contains upper case character.
here is the code.

```
public class Test {

     public static boolean validate(String str)  
        { 
            for (char c : str.toCharArray())  
            { 
                // check if the character is not a lowercase letter 
                if (!(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))  
                { 
                    return false; 
                } 
            } 
            // all characters are lowercase letters 
            return true; 
        } 
      
        public static void main(String args[])  
        { 
            // test cases 
            String example1 = "alCDev-112.am.dev.oneenterprise.com"; 
            String example2 = "ABC123abc"; 
              
            // check if each example contains only lowercase letters 
            System.out.println("Example 1 contains only lowercase letters: " + validate(example1)); 
            System.out.println("Example 2 contains only lowercase letters: " + validate(example2)); 
        } 

}
```

however, it is returning false only in both the cases.
please suggest , how can we use reg ex to check URL should not contain upper case character in java

Comment: Your method returns true if *all* the characters are lower case letters. It even says specifically that's what it does. That is not true for either of your example strings.

Comment: i have given string in all small letters , still it is returning false ....

Comment: @user2315104 Does it return false even when you don't put numbers in the Strings?

Comment: @Senozoid
yes, if i remove all numbers then also it is returning false

Comment: Why use regex intead of fixing the method?

Comment: @aled, yes , i also want to fix this method, but not getting  . please suggest

Comment: Maybe `return !(str.toLowerCase().equals(str);`?

Comment: If you test the string `"abc"` in your method (i.e. only lower case letters, no other characters), the method will return true. That's what that method is written to do.

Comment: @khelwood, yes , but if the string contains the (.) character , it fails , how to fix it

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t add `if (c == '.')` to your loop body?

Comment: The question should be about fixing the issue, not to use another method. Otherwise it is an XY Problem.

Comment: @VGR
i tried adding the code you suggested , its not working .  if (c == '.')
the code is not going to that if condition

Comment: Stop and think about your logic.  If your loop body returns the instant it sees a character which isn’t in the a–z range, then you cannot account for periods.  Therefore, logically, you need to check for a period inside the loop body, *before* checking for a lowercase letter, and you need the *skip the check for a letter* if the character is a period.  All of that can be done with `if` statements.

Comment: "how can we use regex to check URL **should not** contain upper case character in java": `public static boolean validate(String inputString) { return inputString.matches("[\\p{Ll}0-9\\p{Punct}]+"); }`. More [info here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

Comment: @user2315104 Okay so it seems as if you want everything except uppercase letters to be valid. That includes lowercase, numbers, special characters etc... so instead of writing a condition that checks for all the valid cases, why not make the condition check for the only invalid range? I'm suggesting `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` instead of `if (!(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))`. Do you think that solves the problem?